# Insert new data into Athena table without Glue Crawler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I currently have a pipeline, where each 20 minutes, some JSON files are added to an S3 bucket. I would like to run some analytics on the data in the S3 bucket.

In the past, I have used a Glue crawler that analyze the schema and add new data (using subfolder partitioning) into a table in AWS Data Catalog. This however costed me over 6$ running hourly for just three days (about 2000 small new files in three days). As this is a hobby project, I would like to keep the costs to a minimum.

I decided that I would update the Athena table manually, after uplodaing the files to S3 in a lambda function. This should be way more cost-effective. I don't know however if Athena accepts INSERT statements.

**What is the best way to insert new data into Athena manually (using a Python Lambda function for example) ?**

Answer (score 0):

If the schema of the json-files does not change and if you use the crawler only to recognize newly added/created partitions, you can use [partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) to manually define the range / values of your partitions.